# Отобразить xmltype

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, sqldeveloper

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отобразить значение xmltype. Например

```
select xmlelement(b) from
(
select xmltype('<cover>
                <title>Oracle SQL*Loader</title>
                <author>Jonathan Gennick</author>
                <author>Sanjay Mishra</author>
                <pages>269</pages>
              </cover>') b
from dual              
)
```

Необходимо для использования в запросе ((( Процедурные решения в интернете есть

Comment: Не совсем понятно: для отображения или для использования в запросе? "Процедурные решения в интернете есть" - и какие же, не любопытства ради, а для лучшего понимания, что вам всё-таки нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно получить значение `xmlType`:

```
with data as (
    select xmlType ('
        <cover>
            <title>Oracle SQL*Loader</title>
            <author>Jonathan Gennick</author>
            <author>Sanjay Mishra</author>
            <pages>269</pages>
        </cover>') b
    from dual              
)
select d.b.getClobVal () from data d 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть имеете в виду это:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(xmlsequence(xmltype('<cover>
            <title>Oracle SQL*Loader</title>
            <author>Jonathan Gennick</author>
            <author>Sanjay Mishra</author>
            <pages>269</pages>
          </cover>').extract('//title')))
```